# How to get all _id from the nested JSON file using aggregation pipeline?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I had the following array of structure in my aggregation pipeline. Tried merge objects and setUnion operators.

```
{
  "_id": "6085232dd933b53b80a3de0c",
  "parent": "6082b81ea6036499a33d0972",
  "childNodes": [
    {
      "_id": "6084f8376d422a5baf527b6c",
      "childNodes": [
        {
          "_id": "6084f9ab6d422a5baf527b6d",
          "childNodes": [
            {
              "_id": "6084fa356d422a5baf527b6f",
              "childNodes": [
                {
                  "_id": "6084faa06d422a5baf527b70"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "_id": "6084f9ab6d422a5baf527b6d",
          "childNodes": [
            {
              "_id": "6084fa356d422a5baf527b6f",
              "childNodes": [
                {
                  "_id": "6084faa06d422a5baf527b70"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am expecting the following results to produce some statistics.

```
{
 "allNodes":[allChildNodes-_ids]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking about recursive traversal of the document tree. It's not what mongo is good at. Technically you can employ [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) to do in javascript:

```
.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      "allNodes": {
        $function: {
          body: function(doc){
              allIds = function(d) {
                  return [d._id].concat(...((d.childNodes || []).map(allIds)))
              } 
              return allIds(doc)},
          args: [
            "$$ROOT"
          ],
          lang: "js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

but performance will suffer. Tail calls are not optimised either, so be careful with deeply nested documents.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve without $function operation? reduce, map, accumulator any of these operator can help us? @Alex Blex

Comment: To a degree.  There are no recursive functions in mongo yet. Whatever operators you use you will need to stick  to specific depth of nested documents. The question implies you don't know the depth beforehand, is it correct?

Comment: Yes the depth of the array is incremental can't predict